# loop through the html table cells using javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, html-table

I am trying hard to loop through the table cells and insert the values inside them.But i don't know what is wrong with my code.Please help me out.I know there is some silly mistake.Please let me know what it is.
Here is my code-

```
 var data = response.datas.length;
              var table = document.getElementById('itemsval');
              for(var i=0; i<data; i++ ){
                var row = table.insertRow(i);
                for(var j=0; j<7; j++){
                 var cell = row.insertCell(j);


                cell[i][j].innerHTML = response.datas[i].p_name;
                 cell[i][j].innerHTML = response.datas[i].p_details;
                 cell[i][j].innerHTML = response.datas[i].p_qty;
                 cell[i][j].innerHTML = response.datas[i].p_rate;
                 cell[i][j].innerHTML = response.datas[i].p_dis;
                 cell[i][j].innerHTML = response.datas[i].p_tax;
                 cell[i][j].innerHTML = response.datas[i].p_tot; 
                }

              }
```

I keep getting the error- Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `cell[i][j]`? Also, you've said you're trying to "loop through the table cells" but what your code does is **create** table cells. Is the table initially empty? Are you trying to add to it?

Comment: becouse `cell` or `cell[0]` is `undefined`

Comment: yes i am actually creating table cells and then filling them with the values@T.J.Crowder

Comment: i will surely consider your advice but for now help me out with this..@T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first iteration, this line

```
cell[i][j].innerHTML = response.datas[i].p_name;
```

tries to access a property called `0` within `cell`. `cell` won't have a property called `0` (from the variable `i`). If it did, that property's value wouldn't have a property with the name `0` (from the variable `j`) either.

Separately, repeated writing to the same place:

```
cell[i][j].innerHTML = response.datas[i].p_name;
cell[i][j].innerHTML = response.datas[i].p_details;
```

...will cause later values to overwrite earlier values.

Instead, you want to add a cell to the row as you go, and set that cell's content. Let's give ourselves a handy function to do that:

```
function addCell(row, content) {
    var cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(content)
    );
    return cell;
}
```

That adds the cell, sets its content in a way where you don't have to worry about HTML markup, and returns the cell.

Now, let's use it in your code:

```
// Get the table
var table = document.getElementById('itemsval');

// Add the rows
response.datas.forEach(function(entry) {
    var row = table.insertRow();
    addCell(row, entry.p_name);
    addCell(row, entry.p_details);
    addCell(row, entry.p_qty);
    addCell(row, entry.p_rate);
    addCell(row, entry.p_dis);
    addCell(row, entry.p_tax);
    addCell(row, entry.p_tot); 
});
```

Note how that code loops through the `response.datas` array via `Array#forEach`. [You have lots of other options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) *(that's also an answer of mine)*, but it seems the simplest in this case.

Comment: this is awesome...it saved my day...thanks a lot for that explanation.thanks buddy...u mind giving me tutions???Just kidding..anyways thanks